# How to wait for a variable to have a value so I can execute other code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a bit of a JS noob and I tried to search some stuff online but I didn't manage to implement any of the solutions. So, I have this snippet of JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        arr = my_func()
    });

    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/some_url",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                coord: JSON.stringify({
                    "l1": arr[0],
                    "l2": arr[1]
                }),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function(json) {
                window.location.href = "data/";

            },
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And what I need to do basically is, at the click of `#btn`, I need to get the value of `arr` so I can then send an Ajax query, however, it's shown that `arr` is `undefined`. This worked when I had two separate buttons for each step (the call to `my_func` in one button and the Ajax query in another), however, I kinda needed to fuse them together in one button. I've been struggling with this for a while and couldn't do it.

EDIT: As requested, here's the snippet of the my_func() function:

```js
function geoFindMe() {

  const status = document.querySelector('#status');
  const mapLink = document.querySelector('#map-link');

  mapLink.href = '';
  mapLink.textContent = '';

  function success(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    status.textContent = '';
    mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;
    mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`;
    sol = [latitude, longitude];
    console.log(sol)
    return sol;
  }

  function error() {
    status.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
  }

  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
  } else {
    status.textContent = 'Locating…';
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  }
```

Comment: You have two click handlers for the same button ?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand; do you have 1 button which on click should get the value of an array (by calling some function) and at the same time, the same button, on the same click, should send that array to the server... is that correct ?

Comment: Like others have pointed out your .addEventlistener() does exactly the same thing that your .click() does. What you need to do is move `arr = my_func()` to the top of your .click() listener but aove the $ajax-call.

Comment: @V.Sambor Yes, that's exactly what I want!

Comment: @riesa I tried to do that but I get an arr is undefined error

Comment: can we see the content of  `my_func()` it seams that you get your elements asynchroniously... in that case you need a callback

Comment: @V.Sambor I'll edit my answer with the contents of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval` for this using the following code reference:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('pleaseWait');
var counter = 0;

var interval = setInterval(popItUp, 200);

function popItUp() {
  if (text.value.length > 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById('waitingText').innerHTML = 'text entered!!';
    // Apply your ajax here
  } else {
    document.getElementById('waitingText').innerHTML = 'waiting..';
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="popItUp()" type="text" name="pleaseWait" id="pleaseWait" />
<div id="waitingText"></div>
```

This code will wait for the text to be entered in the input field. Once text is entered, interval will be cleared.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/53crh9g4/1/) is the link to the fiddle.

Comment: `arr` is undefined because you haven't declared `arr` in the above snippet until unless its declared somewhere else

Comment: arr is a global variable

Comment: To me the [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/hmng62y3/1/) throws no error, but it doesnt work as its a link from jsfiddle. Maybe you can try some other better methods with this code to achieve your goals.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thank you for your patience. I'll post my solution once I figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

The `my_func` function must return a new instance of `Promise`. Doing that you can use `await` to wait for `arr` to be set and then do your Ajax call.
So let's do an example:

```js
function my_func() {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve('hello'));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            async function arr() {
                arr = await my_func();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/some_url",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        coord: JSON.stringify({
                            "l1": arr[0],
                            "l2": arr[1]
                        }),
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                    success: function(json) {
                        window.location.href = "data/";

                    },
                    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
    }
    arr();
});
```

Comment: This seems to be what I want, however, I need my_func to return the elements of arr. Can I still do this?

Comment: Yeah sure, i suggest you to check out [await documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: Tried to do this, didn't work, I used your example and it always gave me "arr is undefined", moved the ajax query out of the async function after arr(); and after the first click it gives me arr is undefined but works if I click the button a second time.